# Database OUT Parameter doesn't return any data on Java side

Tags: java, sql, oracle, orm, mybatis

I'm fetching data from a package that has a stored proc. The proc has 2 input parameters (Number and Varchar2) and an output parameter (Custom type). When I try to connect to the package and get data on java side, I'm getting an empty list rather than the actual data. Please tell me what I'm missing here. Here's the code :

```
@Mapper public interface NavDataMapper {
@Select("CALL NAV_DATA_DISTRIBUTION.FETCH_NAV_DATA ( #{classificationId, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN}, #{currentBusinessDate, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN}, #{LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT, jdbcType=ARRAY, jdbcTypeName=T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT_LIST, mode=OUT}) ")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultMap("navDataMap")
List<NavData> getNavData(Map<String,Object> navDataParams); }
```

Here's the XML :

```
<resultMap type="model.NavData" id="navDataMap">
    <result column="FundName" property="fundName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String"></result>
    <result column="SFundNum" property="sfundNumber" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String"></result>
    <result column="IFundNum" property="ifundNumber" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String"></result>
    <result column="EffDate" property="effectiveDate" jdbcType="DATE" javaType="String"></result>
    <result column="CurrNAV" property="currentNav" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="BigDecimal"></result>
    <result column="Shares" property="outstandingShares" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="BigDecimal"></result>
    <result column="TNA" property="totalNetAsset" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="BigDecimal"></result>
    <result column="ClassName" property="className" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String"></result>
</resultMap>
```

DB Code :

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY NAV_DATA_DISTRIBUTION AS

    PROCEDURE FETCH_NAV_DATA (
      I_CLASSIFICATION_ID IN NUMBER,
      I_BUSINESS_DATE IN VARCHAR2,
      LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT OUT T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT_LIST
    ) AS
      --  LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT_LIST;
    BEGIN
      SELECT T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT(
               FRFA_FIALTDESC.FI_ALT_MED_NM,
               SAS.FI_AKA_ID,
               INV1.FI_AKA_ID,
               NVL(CMV.EFF_D,TO_DATE(I_BUSINESS_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')),
               NVL(CMV.PRC_A, 0),
               NVL(OS.OUTST_SHARES_A, 0),
               NVL(TOT.TT_NET_ASET_A, 0),
               FRCT_FICLASSTYPE.FI_CLSF_DS
             )
             BULK COLLECT INTO LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT
      FROM   FRCT_FICLASSTYPE,
            ...
      
    FOR i in 1..LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT.COUNT
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT(i).FundName);
      END;
    END LOOP;

  END FETCH_NAV_DATA;

END NAV_DATA_DISTRIBUTION;
```

Custom Type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT AS OBJECT 
( 
FundName VARCHAR2(50),
SFundNum VARCHAR2(12),
IFundNum VARCHAR2(12),
EffDate DATE,
CurrNAV NUMBER(20,9),
Shares NUMBER(20,5),
TNA NUMBER(20,5),
ClassName VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT_LIST 
AS TABLE OF T_NAV_DATA_OUTPUT;
```

Comment: To receive a list of custom objects via OUT parameter, you need to use a custom type handler. See how the `UserListTypeHandler` is used in this [demo project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806). Note that the result is set to the parameter object you passed to the method (i.e. `navDataParams`), not returned as the method result. This is essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56834806/1261766), probably.